# VS2019 - Code Style - Enforce expression body on new line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

It's possible to force the use of expression body "when possible" using:

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> General -> Expression preferences`

However, I'm unable to determine (or find) the knob to force the body onto a new line.

```cs
public int GetNum() => 1;

// vs

public int GetNum() =>
    1;
```

Comment: Did you found find how to enforce ?

Comment: Sadly crickets...

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do that with Visual Studio, but we can do that with Resharper's styling settings.